# Paypal Pro API Error

Tags: paypal

I am using Paypal Pro on my site and when I run any transaction, I get this error message.

"Invalid Merchant Configuration"

Can anyone suggest anything???

I am running out of luck ;(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paypal Invalid Merchant Configuration sandbox error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254503/paypal-invalid-merchant-configuration-sandbox-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you have not agreed to the billing
>   agreement, or the billing agreement is
>   disabled or inactive
>
> — [Paypal API Error Codes](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_errorcodes)

Answer (score 0):

I've received that error message in a few scenarios, including:

- When my PayPal Payments Pro account was not configured correctly due to an error on PayPal's side.
- When I hadn't "Set Up" my PayPal Payments Pro "Hosted Pages" screen.