# Paypal Invalid Merchant Configuration sandbox error

Tags: api, paypal

I am using paypal pro in sandbox. when I send the request and in response I get this error:

Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2010%2d11%2d23T09%3a21%3a12Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 2aa783b64659
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 51%2e0
    [BUILD] => 1620725
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10501
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid%20Configuration
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => This%20transaction%20cannot%20be%20processed%20due%20to%20an%20invalid%20merchant%20configuration%2e
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
    [AMT] => 20%2e00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
)

I google this error and it is something with the "Billing Aggrement"

Can anyone suggest what to do on this?

Answer (score 13):

Click products and enable payment pro sorted it for me.

[image: do]

Update Aug 12, 2013: Enabling PayPal Payments Pro has been moved to the "Profile" tab.  There is no longer a "Products" tab.

Answer (score 8):

The API credentials in the Sandbox environment uses the default buyer account you have. You need to make sure to use the "payments pro" option when you create a buyer account in the sandbox environment. You'll then see a new set of API credentials under API credentials...just use those and you should be fine.

Comment: This is exactly what you need to do. Set up a new test account, and make sure you choose the one that says "PayPal Payments Pro (Use to represent yourself as a merchant using Pro)". After that, go to the "API credentials" and get the new API username, password and signature. Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same problem while trying to use the DoDirectPayment example on the sandbox using the provided API user/pass.

```
L_ERRORCODE0: 10501  
L_SHORTMESSAGE0: Invalid Configuration 
L_LONGMESSAGE0: This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.
```

I logged into my sandbox account, but there was no billing agreement to agree to. Trying to enable Website Payments Pro from there proved fruitless as well.

There seem to be a lot of issues with the Paypal sandbox right now, where test accounts are not populating with the right info. This 10501 problem is due to "Website Payments Pro" not being enabled on the account.

[Contact customer support](http://www.paypal.com/mts) and they can enable it for you. They asked me to create a new test seller account so they could toggle it on.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal is currently working on addressing this issue. You may want to file ticket with MTS (www.paypal.com/mts) to be updated on when it's fixed.

Accounts created before the latest release do have Pro set up correctly. All new accounts have a problem with the billing agreement that affects Pro functionality and results in error 10501.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was using the default Business sandbox account that exists when you set up the PayPal developer account. When I created a new business account everything worked.

Also, be sure to use a personal sandbox account that you set to test against your business sandbox account.