# How to enable dodirectpayment API?

Tags: php, cakephp, paypal

I m working with e-commerce application,
I have setup a Sandbox Test Account and trying to use "DoDirectPayment" API But getting error `"Invalid Merchant configuration"`. I got the information that, I should enable Website Payments Pro. I try to activate in my seller account but m getting error. Please guide me the steps to activate dodirectpayment API.

Thanks,
Pushpa

Comment: This sounds like a case for the API provider's technical support rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: possible duplicate [paypal-invalid-merchant-configuration-error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254503/paypal-invalid-merchant-configuration-sandbox-error)

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new Website Payments Pro seller account and select "United States of America" as the country. I was having a similar problem and this resolved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

this problem occurs due to "Website Payments Pro" not being enabled on the account...

you cannot enable this yourself... so kindly ask the paypal technical support to do so..
provide them with your sandbox account credentials and the seller account you are using, they will enable "WPP" within few hrs... :)