# Implementing a PayPal Pro payment with PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I followed [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-process-credit-cards-with-paypal-payments-pro-using-php/) carefully while entering the right credentials, however I always obtain this error message : « This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration ».

Anybody knows why is that ?

Comment: ... your merchant configuration is invalid?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254503/paypal-invalid-merchant-configuration-sandbox-error

Comment: Thanks Nick I found the solution there ! (my sandbox account wasn't a PayPal Pro sandbox account)