# Paypal Sandbox - Merchant Account

Tags: jsp, paypal-sandbox

I have opened a Business Account on PayPal Developer, and also a personal account.

I have this jsp file :

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body onload="document.forms['paypalForm'].submit();">

<form name="paypalForm" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="MyUserName" />
 <input type="hidden" name="password" value="MyPassword" />
 <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="1123" />
 <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Computer-Laptop" />
 <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="30"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1" />
 <input type="hidden" name="return" value="gallery.jsp" />
 <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="gallery.jsp" />
 <input type="hidden" name="cert_id" value="MySignature" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I type my username, password and signature as they are in API Credentials in PayPal, but when I run it I get this error :

We cannot process this transaction because there is a problem with the PayPal email address supplied by the seller. Please contact the seller to resolve the problem. If this payment is for an eBay listing, you can contact the seller via the "Ask Seller a Question" link on the listing page. When you have the correct email address, payment can be made at www.paypal.com.

Your purchase couldn't be completed

### There's a problem with the merchant's PayPal account. Please try again later.

Any ideas? My sandbox test account is open...

Answer (score 0):

Try this from this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254503/paypal-invalid-merchant-configuration-sandbox-error):

> The API credentials in the Sandbox environment uses the default buyer
>   account you have. You need to make sure to use the "payments pro"
>   option when you create a buyer account in the sandbox environment.
>   You'll then see a new set of API credentials under API
>   credentials...just use those and you should be fine.

Comment: Yes it's the same error. When I did the upgrading to pro, the credentials didn't change